Dynamically Initialize a Kendo Filter Component (ASP.NET Core)
Example: I have a list which contains, for example:

ChildCode1
ChildCode2

And another list which contains

ParentCode1
ParentCode2

With a button, i open a KendoWindow with a Grid of Toys with their data and with a column which shows their owner (the child) and the child's parent. On load, i dynamically set the Grid Filter to filter based on the two aforementioned lists
Meaning that the button will open only Toys owned by ChildCode1 and ChildCode2, and only if ChildCode1 and ChildCode2 have either ParentCode1 or ParentCode2 as a parent.
Now ironically this isn't the difficult part, everything works fine. The grid however, shouldn't be filterable with the standard filter, but instead with a filter component, which can be accessed with a toolbar button that opens another window with the Filter Component.
This means that when the user opens that window, the Filter Component should already show the aforementioned starting filters, instead of being empty.
How can i do this?
(difficult to explain but for company reasons i cannot show code and making an example is difficult)
I tried setting the FilterComponent's expression dynamically, by taking the filter from the grid and inserting it, but it doesn't change the already rendered component
